# Core Data One to many relation not storing its data

Tags: ios, entity-framework, sqlite, core-data, swift2

I have a Table view based app that has a MasterTableViewController and a DetailChildTableViewController.

MasterTableViewController has a + in the Nav bar so a user is presented with a view to enter a name for that Folder in a textfield. Once the user is done, the clock done and this folder is then stored using Core Data and displays this new folder in the MasterTableViewController.

Here is the code for this specific TableViewController

**MasterTableViewController**

```
   class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// Populate fetched results controller
func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController

}


func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}


}
override viewDidLoad(){
fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultController()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch _ {
    }
 }

 // Table View Methods to show data in Custom UITableViewCell and Segue method....
```

The rest of the code in this controller just has methods to display the data in the table view cell and a segue method that passes the Core Data name to the next view controller as the user taps the newly created cell object.

Here is the Code to Create this specific Object to save and display on MasterTableViewController

**AddViewController**

```
class addItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var FolderName: UITextField!

// Use the same managed object to save

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

 @IBAction func Done(sender: AnyObject){

 // Calling a function to save the folder to core data
 saveFolder()
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
 }

// Function that saves

func saveFolder(){
 let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Folder", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    let item = Folder(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    item.name = FolderName.text!


    // Passed Value of the color picker table view below


    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        print("Successfully Saved \n")
    } catch _ {
    }
}

}
```

So this code basically saves the newly entered Folder and dismisses the folder name view and the MasterTableViewController shows this new folder.

The problem lies in the **DetailChildTableViewController** where it is the detail of each **Folder** created in MasterTableViewController.

Here is the code for the final tableview Controller

** DetailChildTableViewController**

```
   class DetailChildTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// Populate fetched results controller
func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController

}


func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemListName", ascending: false)


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(){

    // Core data
    fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultController()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch _ {
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

 // MARK: - Display the results in table view

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}

}
```

This DetailChildTableViewController also has a + button in the navigation bar and brings up a similar AddViewController to add data to this specific folder with the same Core Data methods.

The problem is that when i create 2 entities in my MasterTableViewController, say for example:

- Folder_One
- Folder_Two

and i go into **Folder_Two** and create a list object in this folder and then go back to the MasterTableViewController and then select **Folder_One**, It still shows that same list object which i created in **Folder_Two**.

How can i approach a solution to this simple yet unclear problem?

Here is my Data model by the way:

**TestApp.xcdatamodel**

Entities:

1. Folder
2. List

   Atributes:
   **name** of type String (for **Folder** entity)
   **itemListName** of type String (for **List** entity)

   Relationships: (for **Folder** entity)
   relation *destination*: List

Note that List entity is not listed as having a relationship to Folder. I set **Folder** to have relationship to **List** as a **One to many** relation.

What did i do wrong and how can i approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `DetailChildTableViewController` displays *all* the `List` objects.  You need to restrict it to fetch only the `List` objects related to your current `Folder`.  To do this you must have a relationship from `List` to `Folder`.  This relationship will be to-one, and will be the inverse of the to-many relationship from `Folder` to `List`.  (You should almost always create an inverse for every relationship.  Even if you feel you don't need it, create it anyway.  In this case, as you'll see below, you do need it).  So your entity model should look something like this:

```
Folder          List
======          ====
name            itemListName
lists <------>> folder
```

In your `DetailChildTableViewController`, add a new variable which will be the `Folder` for which you are displaying the `Lists`:

```
var currentFolder : Folder?
```

To limit the fetch so it only displays the `List` objects related to this folder, add a predicate to the fetch request:

```
if let thisFolder = currentFolder {
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"folder == %@",thisFolder)
}
```

When the user taps a cell in the `MasterTableViewController`, before showing the `DetailChildTableViewController`, you must set the correct value for `currentFolder`.  In `prepareForSegue`, you will need something like:

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
let currentFolder = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Folder
detailViewController.currentFolder = currentFolder
```

Similarly, the `AddListViewController` must have a `currentFolder` variable to know which `Folder` the newly created `List` should belong to (and the code in the `DetailChildTableViewController` that segues to it must set the value for `currentFolder`).  In the `AddListViewController`, when you store the `List` item, you need to set the relationship:

```
newList.folder = currentFolder
```

Note that when you set a relationship, CoreData will automatically set the inverse relationship (assuming you defined one).  So the `newList` will be added to the `lists` property of `currentFolder`.

Comment: I have a question, where did `newList.folder` come from? I did all this but this last piece is what i don't recall mentioning or adding in my app

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused with what you are trying to say right where you write "Similarly" as mention different view controllers to which i get lost where exactly i would follow up

Comment: @harreola I used `newList` as an example - substitute the variable name that you use when you create a new `List`.  So `newList.folder` is the `folder` relationship on this newly created object.

Comment: The "Similarly..." paragraph deals with Adding a new `List` (I guessed, perhaps wrongly, that the view controller for adding a new List was called `AddListViewController`).  When you add a new `List`, you need to specify which `Folder` it belongs to - so you need to add `var currentFolder : Folder?` to that view controller (and you must set the value for this variable before displaying that view controller).

Comment: Do you have a sample app of how this actually works?

Comment: @harreola I created a demo based on your code - see [here](https://github.com/pbasdf/DemoMasterDetail.git).

Comment: Thank you so much, now i can clearly understand how this all works since most of my apps will rely on this sort of method. I can finally see how things work with Core Data. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Do you know how i would edit this child element in Core Data?

Comment: I would like to add a screen which a user can tap this child and edit the name

Comment: @harreola That should be relatively straight forward: create a segue from the cell in the `DetailChildTableViewController` to the `AddListTableViewController` and pass the relevant `List` object.