# How do i implement parent child relationship in core data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have a scenario where I need to implement parent-child relationship using core data.

The scenario is, in table view I have a list of teams(the teams can be added through the user input) and in another table view a list of members which is also added through the user input.

Where I stuck is, i couldn't implement the relationship between the two tables. I can add teams and also the members but when I select a team, it displays all the members i added. It should be like, on selecting a team it should show the members related to it not all the members.

Could anyone answer with an example in this scenario otherwise I can show what I have done at the coding part, if needed.

Thanks in advance!

**Team table view controller**

```
class GroupTable: UITableViewController {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var teamData = [Teams]()


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Teams")

    do{
        teamData = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Teams]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if teamData.count > 0{

        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return teamData.count

    } else {
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "No Teams available at the moment, create one!"
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return 0

    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    let teamDetails = teamData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = teamDetails.teamName
    cell.imageView?.image = teamDetails.teamImage as? UIImage
    return cell

}
}
```

**Member table view controller**

```
class MemberTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var memberData = [Members]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Members")

    do{
        memberData = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Members]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    if memberData.count > 0{

        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return memberData.count

    } else {
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "No Members in the team, add one!"
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return 0

    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("memberCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScreenThreeTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let memberDetails = memberData[indexPath.row]

    cell.memberName?.text = memberDetails.memberName
    cell.memberDesignation?.text = memberDetails.memberDesignation
    cell.memberImage?.image = memberDetails.memberImage as? UIImage

    return cell
}
```

**My ER model**
[image]

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35792657/3985749) to a very similar question.

Comment: Yes it is the same, there approach is different except the final part. I need to modify a lot if I have to follow them.

Comment: One side note: entity names are usually singular (eg. Team, not Teams) and relationship names usually indicate the *destination* entity, not the source.  So in the Team entity, the relationship to Member might be called "members", not "teams".  Often people use the plural for the relationship name to indicate that it is to-many.  The to-one relationship from Member to Team would use the singular "team".

Answer (score 4):

Your `viewWillAppear` in the member view controller just fetches all `Members`, so what you're seeing is no surprise. You need to tell the member view controller which of the `Teams` it should be using.

There are multiple ways to do this. One is:

- Add a property in the member view controller of type `Teams`. Something like `var team : Teams?`
- Implement `prepareForSegue` and have it look up the selected team and assign it to the `team` property in the destination view controller. Something like

  ```
  let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
  let selectedTeam = teamData[indexPath.row]
  destinationViewController.team = selectedTeam
  ```
- Use a predicate in the fetch request in the member view controller, something like

  ```
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"team = %@", team)
  ```

Then you'll only fetch `Members` that belong to the selected `Team`.

Comment: Should I implement `prepareForSegue` in my member table view controller? could you give me step by step instructions please 'coz I'm new to iOS development!

Comment: I'm getting an error when i click the '+' button(to add new team), at this line `let selectedTeam = teamData[indexPath.row]`. Says `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I didn't mean that you should copy and paste that code exactly, that's why I repeatedly said "something like".